# Memory consumption issue in Quartz.net core

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am using **Quartz.NET 3.0.7** in my application for some scheduled tasks but when i start scheduler it will increasing memory when scheduler run.i also checked with simple schedule task which print some list of string on console the same issue is happening in this also.i can not understand what is actual issue.my observation is **IJob** object is released after job work done.I have no idea other than that.

I am creating Jobs Dynamically by passing JobType

```
 private IJobDetail GetJobDetailForType<TInput>(string jobKey, string jobGroup) where TInput : IJob
    {
      IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<TInput>()
                                       .WithIdentity(jobKey, jobGroup)
                                       .Build();
      return jobDetail;
    }
```

And initialize schedule jobs in this function

```
  private void InitializeSchedulerJob(ScheduleJob scheduleJob)
    {

        IJobDetail jobDetail;
        ITrigger trigger = this.GetTrigger(scheduleJob.Code.ToString(), tenantCode, scheduleJob.CornSchedule);

        if (scheduleJob.Code == (int)EnumHelper.Scheduler.Job.EmailJob)
        {
          this.logger.LogDebug($"EmailJob");
          jobDetail = this.GetJobDetailForType<EmailJob>(scheduleJob.Code.ToString(), tenantCode);
        }

        this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    }
```

Email Job Code

```
 public class EmailJob : IJob 
  {
    private IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public EmailJob(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
      this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
      if (this.serviceProvider != null)
      {
          JobKey jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;
          IEmailScheduleSendService emailScheduleSendServiceNew = this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEmailScheduleSendService>();
          ILogger<EmailJob> logger = this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<EmailJob>>();
          logger.LogDebug($"FROM EXECUTE METHOD | {jobKey.Name} | {jobKey.Group} | START");
          await emailScheduleSendServiceNew.EmailScheduleSendAsync(context);
          logger.LogDebug($"FROM EXECUTE METHOD | {jobKey.Name} | {jobKey.Group} | END");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a memory profile to find out what is causing the memory consumption?

Comment: Do you use some DI or ServiceLocator?

Comment: Yes.I am using .net core inbuilt DI

Comment: Please show the code how the Jobs are created and how their dependencies are injected. As i remember right, Quartz wants to release the jobs after they ran but .Net Core DI does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start running some performance counters to monitor CPU usage and memory stats and figure out what's going on.

If that doesn't lead you to any obvious answers, it's time to start profiling.

- **[JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)**  (Not free, 30 day trial)
- **[Microsoft's CLR Profiler](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273)**

Comment: I tried using dotTrace but i don't understand how to detect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the services requested by your service locator are not released after use. You can check that by implementing the `IDisposable` interface in one of your requested services and verify that `Dispose()` is called. I guess its not.

To fix that, you can register your services as scoped and open the scope by hand. This will ensure that all service are disposed after use.

```
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    // this check is superfluous and can be omitted. 
    // if you want to ensure that the service locator is there, check this in the constructor.
    // with a good DI framework, it can't be null.
    if (this.serviceProvider != null)
    {
        // open the scope and dispose it after use.
        using (var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            // get the service locator from the scope.
            var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {                   
                JobKey jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;
                IEmailScheduleSendService emailScheduleSendServiceNew = services.GetRequiredService<IEmailScheduleSendService>();
                ILogger<EmailJob> logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<EmailJob>>();
                logger.LogDebug($"FROM EXECUTE METHOD | {jobKey.Name} | {jobKey.Group} | START");
                await emailScheduleSendServiceNew.EmailScheduleSendAsync(context);
                logger.LogDebug($"FROM EXECUTE METHOD | {jobKey.Name} | {jobKey.Group} | END");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogDebug($"SOMETHING WENT WRONG!");
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be event better to register the services as transient.

Comment: @keuleJ i don't think that transient will work, because the .Net Core DI can't track their lifetime. But it's worth a try.

Comment: scoped services shurely need a scope that is disposed to be garbage collected. Transient services don't need a scope to be garbage collected.

Comment: @keuleJ The problem here is that the .Net Core DI can't track the lifetime of a transient service. They will live forever after resolving and the memory leak will still exists. If you know a better way, feel free to add a answer. But this question seems to be abandoned.